# Is the sentence "I'm an American by birth." correct?

Tags: nouns, adjective-phrases, nominalization

Is the sentence "I'm an American by birth." correct? My teacher told me we cannot say "an American".

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49619/are-they-american-or-are-they-americans

Answer (score 2):

"I am an American" is [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans). Your teacher is mistaken here.